# How to use bash to replace specific text from variables in a config file?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a config file. E.g. 
config.cfg

```
product_name = "test_product"
table_name = "test_table"
```

and I have an input file:
input.sql

```
DROP TABLE cg_company_activity_{{product_name}}; 
Select * from {{table_name}}
```

I want to write a bash script that takes in any input file and search and replaces the variables in the config.cfg and returns the transformed text.

OUTPUT:

```
DROP TABLE cg_company_activity_test_product;
Select * from test_table
```

Any idea on how to do this in a bash script? I know Jinja can do this, but I want to avoid python.

Comment: Thanks @john1024 and very impressive indeed ! I also found an approach of using sed and having the config file simply the set of sed commands. E.g. s/{{product_name}}/lenovo/I

The awk script is pretty cryptic  !! Shell scripting is so painful !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F' *= *' 'FNR==NR{gsub(/"/,""); a[$1]=$2;next} {for (k in a)sub("{{" k "}}", a[k])} 1' config.cfg input.sql
DROP TABLE cg_company_activity_test_product; 
Select * from test_table
```

#### How it works

- `-F' *= *'`

  Tells awk to use optional spaces followed by `=` followed by optional spaces as the field separator.
- `FNR==NR{gsub(/"/,""); a[$1]=$2;next}`

  While reading through the first file, config.cfg, (1) remove all `"`, (2) assign the second field, `$2`, as the value for associative array `a` with key `$1`, and (3) skip the remaining commands and jump to start over with the `next` line.
- `for (k in a)sub("{{" k "}}", a[k])`

  For every key `k` in array `a`, look for `{{` k `}}` in the current line and replace it with the value of the associative array `a[k]`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.